# shell script: awk quotation in a single quote trap command

Tags: awk, quotes

Am trying to run the below trap command, which has the awk in it, but it's failing. I am making a mistake in the quotation i feel. Can some please help me:

```
trap 'ssh 0-1 "ps axf | grep $(echo $fname).pcap | grep -v grep | awk '{print \"kill -9 \" \$1}' | sh"' 2
-bash: trap: "kill: invalid signal specification
-bash: trap: -9: invalid signal specification
-bash: trap: ": invalid signal specification
-bash: trap: $1} | sh": invalid signal specification
```

Comment: You have single quotes inside your single quotes. It's sort of obvious here on SO since it highlights the quoted string. Try replacing those single quotes used in your `awk` command with `'"'"'` and see if that makes `trap` happy.

Comment: It's wokring!!! thanks a lot JNevill :). An explanation on your <'"'"'> meaning (within a single quoted trap) will help.